# How to redefine = operator for strings in C++

Tags: c++

How can I perform this code with below details in C++:

```
mystring a;
a="A test text";
```

"mystring" is a class that is defined (by myself) for strings , and other operators like + , == , >> , << , etc are defined in this class.
How can i define a function (a friend function with class) that "=" perform something that I have mentioned.

if there were dictation mistakes, forgive me.

Comment: The same way it is done in STL? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

Comment: Don't create own string classes, use `std::string`.

Comment: Good answers below, but once you've built your string class, look through it carefully, compare it with `std::string`, bin the former, and use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define

```
mystring& operator=(const char*)
```

for this specific assignment to work.

Note that this *overload* returns a reference to self. This allows for *compound assignments*.

Answer (score 1):

*Not* with a friend function. You need to overload the assignment operator :

```
mystring &operator = (mystring const &other) {
    // ...
    return *this;
}
```

Note that you'll also need a conversion constructor that takes in a C-string :

```
mystring(char const *str) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If there was a `mystring(const char *)` ctor (which is a safe assumption), wouldn't that obviate the need for a special `mystring::operator=(const char *)`? Efficiency issues aside.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Wait, I read your comment wrong three times in a row. There's no assignment operator from `char const*` here :)

Comment: Oh. Right! You suggested what I was thinking, too. I need to ask that question to @Bathsheba who suggested a `mystring::operator=(const char *)`.